# PUSHing a lot of hexadecimal numbers

Tags: ida, assembly, hexadecimal

I have the following two lines:

```
  ....
  push 401150h
  call sub_401253
  ....
```

So, when I click on **push 401150h** IDA PRO shows:

```
  seg0001 : 00401120 dword_401120  dd  6F662F3Ch, 3C3E746Eh, 3E702Fh, 253A4E52h, 54522073h
  dd 2073253Ah, 73253A55h, 253A5020h, 656C774h, 616223Dh, 72676B63h, 646E756Fh
  dd 0D73h, 7320703Ch, 335504h, 7265464h, 5484531h 55E4ADEh, A585B5448h, 
  .....(and so on)
```

So, my first question would be : what is this? what it can be?

My own results: that thing which I mentioned above is a string because in the function sub_401253 they copy it using lstrcpy() into a buffer:

```
 ...
 lea eax, [esp+1FC + Buffer]
 ...
 mov edi, [esp+208+arg_0]
 push edi, 
 push eax, 
 call lstrcpy
 ...
```

After that, in a next block the content of the buffer(which are the hexadecimal numbers now) is XORed in a loop. I assume that they encrypt or decrypt it (but that is not so importan for me right now.)

I only want to know what IDA PRO try to depict with **push 401150h** which represents the hexadecimal numbers.
Thats it. I hope you can help me.

best regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data at `00401120` is ASCII-encoded text:

```
3C 2F 66 6F 6E 74 3E 3C 2F 70 3E 00 52 4E 3A 25        </font></p>.RN:%
73 20 52 54 3A 25 73 20 55 3A 25 73 20 50 3A 25        s RT:%s U:%s P:%
77 6C 65 00 3D 22 62 61 63 6B 67 72 6F 75 6E 64        wle.="background
73 0D 00 00                                            s...
```

You can tell IDA to decode those bytes as text by clicking on the data at `00401120` and pressing the <kbd>A</kbd> key

Comment: ok, since I know that the XOR-key is 0A1h, then I must XOR 0A1h with 3C and so on to get the decrypted info...right?

Comment: The data above is already in plaintext (not encrypted), so the `XOR` would apparently be used to encrypt that data. But yes, if it's a single byte key of `A1`, then you'd `XOR` each byte in the string with `A1` to see what the `XOR`'ed result would be.

Comment: ok, thx for your perfect answer.

Comment: You would have spotted this if you had looked at the Hex+ASCII display of your code.